# Remove Bluetooth Permission Message in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Hello we are using bluetooth in Android.
When we turn on bluetooth it give us default dialog "An app wants to turn on Bluetooth" with Deny and Allow buttons. With this message a blue line is shown behind  that dialog which is nothing but a text "Bluetooth Permission". Can we hide or remove this message behind the dialog. I have attached screenshots of the page.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code Snippet

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
           Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
           startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code snippet from where you calling the bluetooth service which is causing this message to be displayed.

Comment: I WANT TO OPEN THE SAME ALERT BOX WITH BLUE LINE REMOVED. WITH YOUR CODE IT WON'T SHOW THE ALERT BOX